# Tensorflow C++ evaluation performance worse than Python one

Tags: python, c++, tensorflow

I built an LSTM classifier in Tensorflow (using Python) and now I am doing a series of benchmarks to measure the execution performance. The benchmark code loads the model that was saved during training and executes it for a number of inputs. I have both a Python benchmark and a C++ one.

I get `5ms` per input when using Python (on CPU) and `68ms` when using C++. I was expecting C++ version to have at least similar performance.

What can cause this difference ? I am not familiar with the internals of Tensorflow, but one of my guesses is that Python version uses BLAS (my numpy is linked with blas) and C++ not. If yes, does that mean that some graph operations are executed in Python ?

Comment: Is the c++ one compiled with optimization flags on?

Comment: Both C++ and Python should use the same backend (based on Eigen) for doing the actual computation so difference is weird. Is there a difference if you execute a large op that's not bandwidth constrained? (ie, multiply two 4k x 4k matrices together)

Comment: Have you find the answer?

Comment: there was something wrong with the build, cleaning and rebuilding somehow solved it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it is too late to post an answer. I faced the same issue and got answer from tensorflow github page:

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/3471

The solution is simple, just use the `-c opt` flag.

Comment: for anyone who finds this later, it looks like the flag is now --config=opt (https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/7259)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try a simpler benchmark to narrow down the problem. The following takes 2-5 seconds on CPU

```
import tensorflow as tf
a=tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([8192, 8192], stddev=0.35))
b=tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([8192, 8192], stddev=0.35))
c=tf.matmul(a, b)

sess.run([tf.initialize_all_variables()])

import time
start_time = time.time()
sess.run(c)
print time.time()-start_time
```

Comment: 10.4 CPU and 0.58 GPU. lscpu:
Architecture:       x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                12
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-11
Thread(s) per core:    2
Core(s) per socket:    6
Socket(s):             1
NUMA node(s):          1
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 62
Stepping:              4
CPU MHz:               1200.117
BogoMIPS:              4190.02
Virtualization:        VT-x
L1d cache:             32K
L1i cache:             32K
L2 cache:              256K
L3 cache:              15360K

Comment: what about timing using C++? You can get graphdef with `print tf.get_default_graph().as_graph_def()`. The init op is called `init:0` and matrix multiplication is `MatMul:0`

Comment: It took 419s ... I guess there is something really wrong with either my box or my code. Here is the code that I used: https://github.com/raduk/tensorflow_tests/blob/master/test.py and https://github.com/raduk/tensorflow_tests/blob/master/test.cc

Comment: Hm, maybe using different of threads? But that wouldn't explain 20x difference in CPU time. Might be worth filing an issue with test.cc repro on this